# How to put caption in package solidity-highlighting.tex

Tags: listings, code

I am using following Latex code for displaying Solidity listing but it does not show any caption. I downloaded the file from [here](https://github.com/s-tikhomirov/solidity-latex-highlighting)

Somebody please guide me how to put caption. Link for project files is: [Project file link](https://github.com/zak100/TemporaryFiles)
My code is:

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen]{acmart}
\usepackage{listings}
\input{solidity-highlighting.tex}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2020}
\acmYear{2020}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}
\begin{document}
\title{A Test of Latex}
\author{A1}
\begin{abstract}
  Testing abstract
\end{abstract}
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002978.10003022</concept_id>
<concept_desc> and application security</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002944.10011122.10002945</concept_id>
<concept_desc>General and reference~Surveys and overviews</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Security and privacy~Software and application security}
\ccsdesc[500]{General and reference~Surveys and overviews}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Solidity] 
contract TestList1{

}
\end{lstlisting}
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sourcefile-bib}


\end{document}
\endinput
```

The output of code is:

[image: Output without Caption].

I am looking for something like this:

[image: Required Output]

Comment: Did you already try with `\begin{lstlisting}[language=Solidity, caption={my caption text}]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, God bless you.